# Passing JSON to Javascript in Laravel – but JS is converting the JSON to HTML Entities

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel

In my Laravel controller, I am creating a multidimensional associative array:

```
$trendChart = Array (
    "series" => Array (
        "data" => Array(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5)
    ),
    "xaxis" => Array (
        "categories" => Array ("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"),
    ),
    "chart" => Array (
        "type" => "line",
        "height" => 350,
    ),
    "stroke" => Array (
        "curve" => "smooth",
    ),
    "dataLabels" => Array (
        "enabled" => false,
    ),
    "fill" => Array (
        "colors" => Array ("#006ba6", "#f23f2b", "#f3f3f3")
    ),
    "annotations" => Array (
        "yaxis" => Array (
            "y" => 4.8,
            "borderColor" => "rgba(155, 199, 0, 1)",
            "borderWidth" => 3,
            "label" => Array(
                "borderColor" => "rgba(155, 199, 0, 1)",
                "style" => Array(
                    "color" => "#fff",
                    "background" => "rgba(155, 199, 0, 1)",
                ),
                "text" => "Ideal Average",
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

I then encode it into JSON, with:

```
$defaultChartOptions = json_encode($trendChart);
```

And then I pass $defaultChartOptions into my view:

```
return view('myview')->with(['defaultChartOptions' => $defaultChartOptions]);
```

Inside my view, I have the following JS:

```
var chartOptions = JSON.parse({{$defaultChartOptions}});
```

For the record, I have also attempted this without the JSON.parse command. Either way, by the time it gets passed to the JS, all of the quote marks have been converted into HTML entities. To view the page source, it looks like this:

```
var chartOptions = {&quot;series&quot;:{&quot;data&quot;:[1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5]},&quot;xaxis&quot;:{&quot;categories&quot;:[&quot;Jan&quot;,&quot;Feb&quot;,&quot;Mar&quot;,&quot;Apr&quot;,&quot;May&quot;,&quot;Jun&quot;,&quot;Jul&quot;,&quot;Aug&quot;,&quot;Sep&quot;,&quot;Oct&quot;,&quot;Nov&quot;,&quot;Dec&quot;]},&quot;chart&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;line&quot;,&quot;height&quot;:350},&quot;stroke&quot;:{&quot;curve&quot;:&quot;smooth&quot;},&quot;dataLabels&quot;:{&quot;enabled&quot;:false},&quot;fill&quot;:{&quot;colors&quot;:[&quot;#006ba6&quot;,&quot;#f23f2b&quot;,&quot;#f3f3f3&quot;]},&quot;annotations&quot;:{&quot;yaxis&quot;:{&quot;y&quot;:3,&quot;borderColor&quot;:&quot;rgba(229, 78, 78, .65)&quot;,&quot;borderWidth&quot;:3,&quot;label&quot;:{&quot;borderColor&quot;:&quot;rgba(229, 78, 78, 1)&quot;,&quot;style&quot;:{&quot;color&quot;:&quot;#fff&quot;,&quot;background&quot;:&quot;rgba(229, 78, 78, 1)&quot;},&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Your Average&quot;}}}}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Add to the output by console.log(chartOptions). And add it so that we can see what does it returns after json parse...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, doing

```
var chartOptions = JSON.parse({{$defaultChartOptions}});
```

do:

This will prevent the data to be escaped

```
var chartOptions = {!! ($defaultChartOptions) !!};
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get that by changing:

```
var chartOptions = JSON.parse({{$defaultChartOptions}});
```

to:

```
var chartOptions = {!! ($defaultChartOptions) !!};
```

and your problem will be solved.